# NodeJS Hangs on Ubuntu 14.04 Boot [Big CPU & Memory usage]

Tags: 14.04, cpu, nodejs

**Node** somehow hangs on **Ubuntu 14.04** boot. It uses lots of CPU and RAM (*Checked with Terminal -> top*). I need to have **root** permissions to kill it and it doesn't work after the first time. Had to spam **killall** and **top -> k** so it vanished after some time.

I guess it shouldn't even be supposed that **node** somehow starts up with Ubuntu booting without any configuration.

Anyone having similar issues?

Installed it from this **PPA**: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

**Edit**:
If I send kill signals to node all the time it seems like a new instance of node appears. I guess there are either many instances of node running at the same time or it restarts when killed. As I wrote before, it vanishes after a while spamming **sudo killall node** but don't know if the killing has an effect or it leaves by itself after some time.

**Edit #2**:
**sudo killall -9 node** seems to kill it. Looks like it **ignores SIGTERM** so **SIGKILL** needs to be used **(-9)**. That's still a temporary solution though. Any ideas why it autostarts when booting Ubuntu and where to disable that? I've already configured the **Startup Applications** program to show hidden processes, but it's not listed there.

Comment: The only 2 packages I've installed with **npm** are **coffee-script** and **reload**. + all dependencies ofc.

Comment: Oh here is the SA question where I found about the **SIGTERM/SIGKILL** problem with **node**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075287/node-express-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-kill-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, and I found out that the issue is related with the `reload` npm package and its executable name when installed with the global flag (`npm install -g reload`).

As I can tell, Ubuntu 14.04 (don't know about other Ubuntu versions or flavors) has an executable called `reload`, pertaining to [the `initctl` suite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/initctl.8.html).

So, the only solution so far is to not to install `reload` globally.

[I've reported this bug to the developer.](https://github.com/jprichardson/reload/issues/13) Make sure to check that report for any changes.